# SurfaceView with setContentView

Tags: android

I have a surface view that places an image as background of my canvas and another as a drag and drop image on top of the first picture. That part of my code works fine(except that when it launches the screen is black until I touch it) then the background image appears and everything works fine. This activity runs full screen without a setContentView call, so I want to use an activity layout to add a button to launch the next activity.

setContentView(R.layout.image_edit_activity);

```
          public class ImageEditActivity extends Activity {

        public String reportDate;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.image_edit_activity);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            reportDate = intent.getStringExtra("reportDate");


            int w=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()-25;
            int h=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-25;

            Crosshair crosshairView = new Crosshair(this,w,h, reportDate);


            //app works fine without this line, but I think this is the key to 
                    //have the surfaceview inside the activity layout.xml
            crosshairView = (Crosshair) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        }
    }




    class Crosshair extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private Bitmap bitmap ;
        private int x=20,y=20;int width,height;
        String reportDate1;

        public Crosshair(Context context,int w,int h, String reportDate) {
            super(context);

            reportDate1 = reportDate;
            width=w;
            height=h;
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/VibrationMeasurement/" + reportDate1 + ".machine" + ".jpg";  

            Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, width, height, true);

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.crosshair);

           // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);//To make background 
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaled,0,0,null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,x-(bitmap.getWidth()/2),y-(bitmap.getHeight()/2),null);

     //       canvas.drawBitmap(;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            x=(int)event.getX();
            y=(int)event.getY();

            if(x<25)
                x=25;
            if(x> width)   
                x=width;
            if(y <25)
                y=25;
            if(y > height)
                y=height;



            updateCrosshair();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        private void updateCrosshair() {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (getHolder()) {
                    this.onDraw(canvas);
                }
            }
            finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

and here is the xml file:

```
                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

          <com.effbe.accelerometer.ImageEditActivity.Crosshair
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ok_button"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to run the app it throws a NoClassDefFoundError for Crosshair class.

Logcat

```
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): Process: com.effbe.accelerometer
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity   ComponentInfo{com.effbe.accelerometer/com.effbe.accelerometer.ImageEditActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.effbe.accelerometer.ImageEditActivity.Crosshair
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.effbe.accelerometer.ImageEditActivity.Crosshair
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): 
 04-23 21:12:28.618: E/AndroidRuntime(27487): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  Didn't find class "com.effbe.accelerometer.ImageEditActivity.Crosshair" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.effbe.accelerometer-1.apk"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the three constructor everytime you use a class to xml.

```
    public Crosshair(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public Crosshair(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public Crosshair(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}
```

Comment: That is not the problem.

Comment: I added the constructors, but I still have the same error.

Comment: @Chrystian Why are you instantiating the crosshairView and instantiante it again??? remove the line Crosshair crosshairView = new Crosshair(this,w,h, reportDate); just put Crosshair crosshairView;